# reCAPTCHA doesn't work with Tor Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, google, captcha

Is it supposed to be a joke? I can't create an account for a Tor forum with the Tor Browser. reCAPTCHA won't work. Actually it's not the problem of this forum only. The reason I got here is... reCAPTCHA doesn't work with Tor Browser.
[image: we can't process your request right now]

I get the error message:  "We're sorry, but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now."
With Chrome everything works fine. Anyone knows how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, very likely. Didn't find it. Still wondering how do I change the exit node in the tor browser.

Comment: ctrl-shift-l or onion -> new tor circuit for this site

Comment: The problem is with Captcha, not Tor browser. Captcha is extremely flawed and actually hinders access to any site it is installed on. Thousands of users are complaining yet Google deflects the question and refuses to answer or even acknowledge that there IS a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I lowered the security slider to the lowest level, did the reCaptcha, then slid it back to where I had it before. It works every time for me, give it a try.